# How to pass res.json as a callback function?

Tags: javascript, express, callback

I have a function with a callback parameter. I use it this way, and it works just fine: 
`DB.last(user,(data) => res.json(data));` 
I tried to rewrite it to something like this, to make it more readable:
`DB.last(user,res.json);`

where DB.last is

```
  static last(user, callback) {
    let data = {name: user, registered: new Date()};
    callback(data);
  }
```

The function call DB.last is in an express router script of course.

I think I see the difference between the two but it seems logical to me to pass res.json to my DB module as a callback parameter (I mean I can pass a function in JS), but it won't work this way.

What am I missing? Why won't this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `res.json.bind(res)`.

When you call `res.json()`, it is executed on the `res` object (i.e. `this` value refers to `res` when the function is executed). However, when you pass `res.json` as a callback parameter, and then call it as `callback()`, it is executed on the object which is `this` in the context where `callback()` is called.

Using the [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method forces the function to be called on `res`. Whenever you call the bound function, its `this` value will always be `res`.